# sql producing duplicate column id on join?

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to only show one id column which is used to join on other tables?

This query produces two id columns used to join each other as primary and foreign key. I only want it to repeat the id column once.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
JOIN productimg ON products.id = productimg.id 
WHERE products.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Query results:

```
id    name     cid  stk prc    id       url
 1  product1    1   10  3000    1   /static/images/dresses/td1.jpg
 2  product2    2   10  2500    2   /static/images/dresses/td2.jpg
 3  product3    2   4   4000    3   /static/images/dresses/td3.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to only show one id column which is used to join on other tables?

Yes.

*Explicitly state* the columns that you want to retrieve in your query.

This allows you to retain control over *how many* fields are retrieved, the *order* in which those fields are retrieved, and any "renaming" (aliasing) that you want/need to do as part of the retrieval.

```
SELECT 
  p.id 
, p.name 
, p.cid 
, p.stk 
, p.prc
, i.url
FROM products p 
JOIN productimg i USING (id)
WHERE p.id IN (1, 2, 3) 
ORDER BY p.id ;
```

> SELECT * ...

*Never* use "Select *" in Production code.

If someone [else] were to extend your neat, tidy, little, three-column table by adding twenty blob fields, your application performance would go through the floor, with your code retrieving all of these "monster" columns for *absolutely no reason*, because your code makes no use of them!

Comment: I thought explicitly stating the columns but it would make the code long and time consuming writing it. But the reason you have given for it to never use Select * in production code, makes sense and totally worth it.

Comment: I really like your answer, thanks for reaching out :))

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to only show one id column which is used to join on other tables?

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
JOIN productimg USING (id)
WHERE products.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

USING collapses two columns into one which is placed first. If more than one column is used for joining they are listed according to the position in USING clause text. So the output columns order is: `<columns from USING><other columns from 1st table><other columns from 2ndt table>`.

If LEFT JOIN is used then the values are taken from left table.

You may to refer to a column in definite table specifying the table alias  (really - needed only in the case of LEFT JOIN for to refer to right table).

The same is applicable to NATURAL JOIN (it is an equivalent of USING when all common columns are listed in joining expression).

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0e6e65ef7bc95c193095ade99cec727d)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.*, productimg.url
  FROM products JOIN productimg
  ON products.id = productimg.id
  WHERE products.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This can be used as well: `SELECT *  FROM products JOIN productimg USING (id)`, if the joining columns have identical names.